# Remove NSArray duplicate Items

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray, nsdictionary, plist

How I remove Plist repeated values in Swift?

```
if let bundlePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Places", ofType: "plist") {

    if let dicionario = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: bundlePath) {
        places = dicionario["places"] as? NSArray
        //places = Array(Set(places)) 
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

I've tried to use `places = Array(Set(places))` but I have an error

Can I convert NSArray to Array?

Comment: Can you cast `places` to `Array` instead of a`NSArray`? `places = dicionario["places"] as? Array<Type>`

Comment: I tried this and showed an error

Comment: What type did you put in for `<Type>`. What was the error? What type is and element of `places` supposed to be?

Comment: I put `<String>`. `places` is a Array that contains dictionaries. The error is: **Thead 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)**

Comment: This error appears in the function: `numberOfRowsInSection` when I `return (places?.count)!`

Comment: how is `places` declared? does `cellForRow......` gets called?

Comment: That exception would indicate that `places` was nil at some point and so the force unwrap failed. You could use `return places?.count ?? 0`